# EditTexts em posição errada

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eu estou criando uma lista de EditTexts de forma programatica. Em todos eu dou uma margin de 20dp e coloco um abaixo do outro. O problema é que o textbox2 sempre fica encima do 1, os outros textbox ficam na posição perfeita. segue o código escrito para criar os edit texts:

```
int numeroParcelas = 15;
for (int e = 0; e < numeroParcelas; e++){
    final EditText myEditText = new EditText(mRlayout.getContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myEditText.setId(e);
    myEditText.getLayoutParams();
    myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    myEditText.setHint("Parcela " + (e + 1) + ":");
    myEditText.setHintTextColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    myEditText.setTextSize(20);
    if ( e > 0 ) {
        editParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, e -1 );
        editParams.setMargins(0,20,0,0);
    }else{
        editParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    }
    myEditText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
    mRlayout.addView(myEditText);
}
```

Segue um print do resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você tirar a linha do `editParams.setMargins(0,20,0,0);`, o que acontece?

Comment: Vai ficar todos os EditTexts um encima do outro

Comment: E se ao invés de colocar dentro do `if`, você colocar logo antes do `myEditText.setLayoutParams(editParams);` após o `}`?

Comment: Da na mesma. na verdade esse if foi um teste que eu fiz apenas

Answer (score 0):

Tente remover o if/else para deixar apenas 
 `editParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, -1 );` acho que pode dar certo, pois até onde eu notei quando `e > 0` (parcela 2) está criando um edittext na mesma posição que o primeiro item, só que com margem de 20 na vertical (que foi definida no setMargins)